# Pass filtered objects from parent component to child component asynchronous

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

In my code snippet below I encountered the following problem.

The `console.log(uniques)` is returning all the filtered events correctly, so next I `return` `uniques` to make them available in my parent component.

When trying to access the `events` in my parent component though, they return `undefined`. So `console.log(eventsFiltered)` in the parent is `undefined`. My guess is that in my child component I should `return` `uniques` in a more `asynchronous` way? But I don't know how to write it correctly.

If someone could look into it I would be very thankful

```
// Childcomponent    
export const filterDateRange = async (dateRange) => {
  const startDate = new Date(dateRange.startDate).getTime()
  const endDate = new Date(dateRange.endDate).getTime()
  let newArray = []

  return axios
    .get(`fetchAllEventsHere`)
    .then((res) => {
      res.data.events.map((item) => {
        item.dates.map((date) => {
          const evtDate = new Date(date).getTime()
          if (evtDate >= startDate && evtDate <= endDate) {
            newArray.push(item)
            let uniques = [...new Set(newArray)]
            console.log(uniques) // This returns the event objects as expected
            return uniques
          }
        })
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err
    })
}


 // Parentcomponent
 useEffect(async () => {
    if (dateRange?.startDate && dateRange?.endDate) {
      const eventsFiltered = await filterDateRange(dateRange)
      console.log(eventsFiltered) // trying to access the events here results in undefined
      setEventsFiltered(eventsFiltered)
    }
 }, [dateRange])
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `filterDateRange` is not a react component right? it's just a function

Comment: Exact miraj! :)

Comment: can you try this `setEventsFiltered(() => eventsFiltered)

Comment: I tried this but no result. Also the problem is that the line above `console.log(eventsFiltered)` still returns `undefined`

Comment: can you create a sandbox pls?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set callback function of useEffect to async since that doesn't works.
Try to define another async function and call the api and then call that function in the useEffect.

### Edited:

You did this -

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    if (dateRange?.startDate && dateRange?.endDate) {
      const eventsFiltered = await filterDateRange(dateRange)
      console.log(eventsFiltered) // trying to access the events here results in undefined
      setEventsFiltered(eventsFiltered)
    }
 }, [dateRange])
```

Rather -

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async ()=> await apiCall())()
 }, [dateRange])

const apiCall = async () {
      if (dateRange?.startDate && dateRange?.endDate) {
          const eventsFiltered = await filterDateRange(dateRange)
          console.log(eventsFiltered) // trying to access the events here results in undefined
          setEventsFiltered(eventsFiltered)
    }
}
```

### Edited(2):

You can declare the uniques variable outside the map and return it outside the map also.

```js
export const filterDateRange = async (dateRange) => {
  const startDate = new Date(dateRange.startDate).getTime()
  const endDate = new Date(dateRange.endDate).getTime()
  let newArray = []

  return axios
    .get(`fetchAllEventsHere`)
    .then((res) => {
      let uniques; // declare here
      res.data.events.map((item) => {
        item.dates.map((date) => {
          const evtDate = new Date(date).getTime()
          if (evtDate >= startDate && evtDate <= endDate) {
            newArray.push(item)
            uniques = [...new Set(newArray)]
            console.log(uniques) // This returns the event objects as expected
          }
        })
      })
     return uniques; // return here
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err
    })
}


 // Parentcomponent
  useEffect(() => {
    (async ()=> await apiCall())()
 }, [dateRange])

const apiCall = async () {
      if (dateRange?.startDate && dateRange?.endDate) {
          const eventsFiltered = await filterDateRange(dateRange)
          console.log(eventsFiltered) // trying to access the events here results in undefined
          setEventsFiltered(eventsFiltered)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the filterDateRange isn't returning any value.

Comment: Yes it does, I `console.log` `uniques` and all the documents are being logged there, it's the `return` at the end of `filterDateRange` that isn't working

Comment: Yes I said so. The function filterDateRange isn't returning anything.

Comment: Ah ok, but how can I fix this than? Because I literally say `return` `uniques`. I don't see the problem

Comment: I would recommend to keep different functions for api call and filtering.

Comment: This problem is arising because you are returning within another callback function. So the `return uniques` is the return of callback function within map not of the axios. One possible solution is to declare the uniques variable outside the map and return the same outside the map.

Comment: samesies... :'(